# How can I open an application using the command line and then close the terminal without closing the opened application?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, zsh, gnome-terminal

If I open an application from the command line, say Firefox, the application runs as long as the terminal stays open. Closing the terminal's tab will close the application.

Is there a way to open an application from the terminal such that the application will stay open even after closing the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open in the background with the addition of an `&; disown`:

```
$ firefox &; disown
```

(Thanks for the correction, I missed the zsh part)

Comment: This is a partial solution. The application will run in the background, yet you won't be able to close the terminal session - zsh: you have running jobs. @nerdwaller

Comment: make that `firefox &; disown`, and it will do what they want

Comment: As you are using `zsh`, benefit from its elegance `;)`and just use `firefox &!`