# FreeBSD: one-line command for an xterm window to sudo open an application, then close xterm whilst the app continues to run

Tags: terminal, sudo, freebsd

I'd like GKrellMLaunch to:

- essentially, use `sudo` to open a GUI application

– present an xterm window for entry of the password, then close the xterm window whilst the application continues to run.

Re: https://superuser.com/a/597075/84988 I tried this:

`/usr/local/bin/xterm -e sudo virtual_oss_ctl -f /dev/vdsp.ctl &; disown`

[image]

– the xterm window remains open.

[Execute Command with xterm and close](https://superuser.com/questions/1301819/execute-command-with-xterm-and-close) – on Linux – has two answers but neither is an answer for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing an `exit`.

```
/usr/local/bin/xterm -e sudo virtual_oss_ctl -f /dev/vdsp.ctl &; disown; exit
```

Comment: The xterm window remains open until I close the Virtual OSS Control window. I need the xterm window to close.